Kafka is giving me a problem in setting up two Brokers on the same local machine, settings are okay but whenever i start the second broker it fails
I am new to Kafka, and I am trying to set up two brokers on my machine. Here is my server.properties file for the two brokers:
broker.id=1
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9091
num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
log.dirs=/Users/qatel/Documents/Projects/myKafka/kafka-log-2
num.partitions=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1
log.retention.hours=168
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=18000
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0

broker.id=0
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092
num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
log.dirs=/Users/qatel/Documents/Projects/myKafka/kafka-log-1
num.partitions=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1
log.retention.hours=168
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=18000
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0


[2024-12-18 14:30:08,141] INFO
[zk-broker-1-to-controller-alter-partition-channel-manager]: Recorded
new ZK controller, from now on will use node localhost:9092 (id: 0
rack: null) (kafka.server.NodeToControllerRequestThread) [2024-12-18
14:30:08,165] INFO
[zk-broker-1-to-controller-forwarding-channel-manager]: Recorded new
ZK controller, from now on will use node localhost:9092 (id: 0 rack:
null) (kafka.server.NodeToControllerRequestThread)


2024-12-18 14:30:07,835] INFO [Controller id=0, targetBrokerId=1]
Client requested connection close from node 1
(org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient) [2024-12-18 14:30:07,938]
INFO [Controller id=0, targetBrokerId=1] Node 1 disconnected.
(org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient) [2024-12-18 14:30:07,938]
WARN [Controller id=0, targetBrokerId=1] Connection to node 1
(localhost/127.0.0.1:9091) could not be established. Node may not be
available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient) [2024-12-18
14:30:07,938] INFO [Controller id=0, targetBrokerId=1] Client
requested connection close from node 1
(org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)

I don't get how

[2024-12-18 14:44:06,429] INFO Awaiting socket connections on
localhost:9092. (kafka.network.DataPlaneAcceptor) [2024-12-18
14:44:06,432] INFO [KafkaServer id=0] Start processing authorizer
futures (kafka.server.KafkaServer) [2024-12-18 14:44:06,432] INFO
[KafkaServer id=0] End processing authorizer futures
(kafka.server.KafkaServer) [2024-12-18 14:44:06,433] INFO [KafkaServer
id=0] Start processing enable request processing future
(kafka.server.KafkaServer) [2024-12-18 14:44:06,433] INFO [KafkaServer
id=0] End processing enable request processing future
(kafka.server.KafkaServer) [2024-12-18 14:44:06,441] INFO Kafka
version: 3.9.0 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2024-12-18 14:44:06,441] INFO Kafka commitId: a60e31147e6b01ee
(org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser) [2024-12-18
14:44:06,442] INFO Kafka startTimeMs: 1734522246433
(org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser) [2024-12-18
14:44:06,443] INFO [KafkaServer id=0] started
(kafka.server.KafkaServer) [2024-12-18 14:44:06,570] INFO
[zk-broker-0-to-controller-forwarding-channel-manager]: Recorded new
ZK controller, from now on will use node localhost:9091 (id: 1 rack:
null) (kafka.server.NodeToControllerRequestThread) [2024-12-18
14:44:06,584] INFO
[zk-broker-0-to-controller-alter-partition-channel-manager]: Recorded
new ZK controller, from now on will use node localhost:9091 (id: 1
rack: null) (kafka.server.NodeToControllerRequestThread)

always happens when I start a second broker.

Use minikube and strimzi. It'll automatically configure as many brokers as you want
